# Eager Fetch has-many relation using NodeJS/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have following models:

```
LeaderSchema = new app.mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    projects: [{ type: app.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Project'}]
});

ProjectSchema = new app.mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    leader: { type: app.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Leader'}
});

Leader = app.mongoose.model('Leader', LeaderSchema);
Project = app.mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

What I want to do in my controller is to retrieve **all projects with its respective leaders**:

projects_controller.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.ProjectsController = {
        index: function(req, res) {
            app.Project.find(function(err, projects) {
                res.send(projects)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But this is giving as result the list of projects with only their **leader's id**

Is there a way to make mongoose **eagerly fetch the leaders**?

Answer (score 0):

Although I would like a solution that **defines the eager load behavior on the model**, the solution I've found is using `populate`:

```
app.Project.find().populate('user').exec(function(err, projects) {
    res.send(projects)
})
```

Documentation for `populate` can be found [here at mongoosejs.com](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).